# Main box amp requirement for 2.4 amp refrigerator

Tags: electrical-panel

My LG refrigerator has a 2.4 amp rating. What size breaker do I need For this? The only other on this line is a GFCI with three plugs.

Comment: Where on the planet are you? Where in your house are the other receptacles on the circuit located? What loads do they serve?

Comment: In the USA, this would automatically be "any 15A or 20A circuit". But LG is very much an international brand, so we need to know where you are.

Comment: 1,5mm^2 with C10A breaker is the minimum allowed by CEI.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming USA/Canada: 15A if it's 14Ga copper wire, 15 or 20A if it's 12Ga copper wire. I'm personally not a fan of sharing the refrigerator or freezer circuits with any other load due to the possibility that the other load will trip the circuit and spoil your food.

If the other outlets are in the kitchen, that's required to be 20A if it's one of the two required countertop outlet circuits.

Comment: If it's serving countertop outlets period, even

Comment: Breakers are sized to protect the wiring, not to protect specific appliances.  so @Ecnerwal is correct.

Answer (score 0):

In the US a typical convenience receptacle will be protected by a breaker that is legally sized to protect that fridge. The only conflict would be if you have other devices plugged into that circuit that the instructions that come with that appliance specify using a dedicated circuit.

Comment: Thank you. The only use of the GFCI circuits is occasional rice cooker. I am located in the USA.

Comment: @RayKreiner the expected way of saying "thank you" is to click the "up vote" arrow for any and every answer you find helpful. It's also expected that you click the check mark next to the answer that you found _most_ helpful in resolving your issue.